# Sorting by imaginary part in MatLab

Tags: matlab, sorting, complex-numbers

So I have a vector that contains complex values.  I want to sort them in order of ascending imaginary order.  Is there a way to do this?

Accorsing to the sort documentation, `sort` will sort via magnitude.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
a = [1 + 1i; 1 - 1i; 1 - 2*1i];
[sorted, idx] = sort(imag(a));
a = a(idx);

a = 

1.0000 - 2.0000i
1.0000 - 1.0000i
1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

Comment: @yankeefan11 Note that if you are only interested in the index, recent versions of Matlab encourage you to make the call like this: `[~, idx] = sort(imag(a))` This way you won't have an unused variable.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I agree, but some older versions of Matlab do not understand the `~` syntax.